# Add dynamic comments to Excel cells via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, comments

I am trying to use comments to show the current due date of a Task via a VBA Macro. My current solution looks like so:

```
Sub AddDueDates()
Dim strPrefix As String
  strPrefix = ""
  With Range("Target")
If .Comment Is Nothing Then
   .AddComment
End If
.Comment.Visible = True
.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
  End With

 With Range("Target").Comment
.Text strPrefix & Range("Source").Text 
End With
End Sub
```

I am terribly aware, that this likely is sloppy code, but i am just starting out again.

The solution so far works fine for a single cell. I named the cells "Target" and "Source" beforehand instead of using cell references such as "B12". Now I want to extend that to multiple cells, depending on the range i select beforehand (e.g. A1:A6).

The selection where comments will be added, will correspond to a range of equal size in a different worksheet.

I feel like a loop will be helpful, but i don't know where to start.

The picture below might illustrate what i want to do.
The source is filled with dynamic dates which i want to add to my comments

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsfEa.jpg

thanks in advance

Comment: You would just need to look up how to create a range, and loop through it cell by cell.

Comment: thanks batman :) Would you mind giving me a hint as to where to start?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. This works with your sample photo - but will need tweaking if the Comment Source is a different worksheet.

```
Sub AddDates()
Dim targetRng As Range, commentSrcRng As Range
Dim strPrefix As String ' why this variable? You never seem to use it

Set targetRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the target range.  This is the range that will have comments added to each cell", Type:=8)
Set commentSrcRng = targetRng.Offset(0, 3) ' from the screenshot. Will have to tweak if this is a different worksheet.

Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
For Each cel In targetRng
    If cel.Comment Is Nothing Then
        cel.AddComment
    End If
    cel.Comment.Visible = True
    cel.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    cel.Comment.Text strPrefix & commentSrcRng.Cells(i)
    i = i + 1
Next cel

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Much obliged, Batman! :) I knew, you not only know your way around gotham! I'll give this a go!

Comment: Just tried this moments ago and it works wonderfully, but as you already have foreseen, I need the comment source from another worksheet. I'll be looking into that since I recon it got somethin to do with the targetRng, but If you could give me pointers again - holy VBA-Batman! :-)

Comment: @James where on the second worksheet are the comments, how would you find them?

Comment: I amended your code with  commentSrcRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the source range.  This is the range that will have the source of the comments", Type:=8)

Comment: I think I am relatively satisifed with the current approach, Thanks a lot! - Hower, I'd like to implement another Macro which just refreshes the attached Comments to reflect recent changes